# Having an additional 1 blank page after PDF generation

Tags: php, sql, pdf

I am generating a PDF from a SQL Server database from my web, everything is normal except the PDF file always has an extra 1 blank page at the end. I am not sure if the problem is here in my stored procedure or in my web, but can you check this one for me?

```
    @gfromDate VARCHAR(10),
    @gtoDate VARCHAR(10) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fromDate DATE
    DECLARE @toDate DATE
    DECLARE @totaldays INT

    SET @fromDate = (SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gfromDate, 101))
    SET @toDate = (SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), @gtoDate, 101))

    SET @totaldays = (SELECT datediff(day, @fromdate, @toDate) + 2)

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''
    DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @counter INT = 1

    WHILE @counter < @totaldays
    BEGIN
        SET @tablename = ((SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @fromDate, 106), 8)), ' ', '') AS [Mon-YYYY]))

        SET @tablename = replace(@tablename, ' ', '')

        SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT 
            accname,
            add1,
            add2,
            zip,
            stat,
            statdate,
         FROM gen_048_' + @tablename + ' WHERE refdate = ''' + REPLACE(convert(VARCHAR(10), @fromDate), '-','') + ''''

        IF (@counter != @totaldays - 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + ' union '
        END

        SET @fromDate = dateadd(day, 1, @fromDate)
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
END

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

I believe this is my PDF generation code am I right? I am using codeigniter as my framework and here is my code in controller.

```
function dormancy()
{
    $data['gfDate']= $this->input->post("fdate");
    $data['gtDate']= $this->input->post("tdate");
    $data['print']= $this->input->post("print");
    $this->load->library('mpdf');
    $this->load->model('mpdf_model');
    $query = $this->mpdf_model->mpdf_gen020($data);

        if($query!=null)
                {
                foreach($query as $data){
        $hello .='
                <img src="'.base_url().'images/ubplogo.png"> </img>
                ';

            $hello.=' TESTING
            <p style="text-align: center;"> This is a system-generated form. No signatures are required</p>
            <br/>   <pagebreak />
            ';
        }
        $mpdf=new mPDF('ISO-8859-1','letter', 10, 'Arial', 15, 15, 16, 16, 9, 9, 'P');

            $stylesheet = file_get_contents(base_url().'css/pdf.css');

            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

            $mpdf->cacheTables = true;
            $mpdf->simpleTables=true;
            $mpdf->packTableData=true;

            $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
            $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="'.base_url().'css/edrsletter.jpg"></img>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($hello);
            $mpdf->SetFooter(' Sample PDF template  - {PAGENO}');
            $mpdf->Output();
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, the only thing your sql query here does is return data. you would need to look at your PDF generation code.

Comment: I included the php codes in my post can you check it?